# How to connect Bones

Tags: modeling, rigging

[image]

Tried Parenting, Rigify, and outright making my own rig from scratch but I can't seem to get this bot to move fluently, Would very much appreciate a point in the right direction! Got the model from open3dlab and get the feeling that all of em are like this and that I'm missing a vital step for it all to click, ya know?

Edit:
While connection fixed the problem of flying limps,
Now they're as stiff as a bored, I can get them to
move (at all some times) like this https://youtu.be/f2pTkW-1JkE?t=331

Appreciate the help,
I'm gonna need more of it.

[image]

Comment: You moved a bone and it moved with its children and associated mesh parts. Can you explain here what you expect to happen differently?

Comment: To my understanding, you are trying to pose your character. It appears that you have moved a bone and its associated mesh parts in `Edit Mode` before going into `Pose Mode`. So - what you will need to do is - while in edit mode, move the leg bone back into position AND THEN go into pose mode to begin the animation process. If i've misunderstood your issue, try attaching a gif and providing further explanation

Comment: @Gunt.r ... screen is taken from Pose mode

Comment: @L0Lock Needed the model to move like this, Instead at the moment, it's either coming apart or like a leaver on a heng. Was shooting for this https://youtu.be/f2pTkW-1JkE?t=331

Comment: @Gunt.r Did all my posing in Pose mode, I don't think it's possible to move both the mesh and bones at the same time otherwise. Or Is there?

Comment: Please ... ask one question per thread ... this site is meant to be as knowledge base so others can search questions similar to their issue. Please change title to something more descriptive so others can discover it. Thank you keep this site organised.

Comment: @vkidu oh I gotcha! Sorry about that, This is my first post here and I'm still trying to get the gist of it all like I am with animation.

Answer (score 1):

Check in Edit mode if Bone is set as **Connected** under *Bone Properties > Relations*

From what is seen in your screen, the checkbox seems to be unchecked ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips though unfortunately no dice. The legs seems to be frozen in place now when I'd really like for it to move in this fashion,  https://youtu.be/f2pTkW-1JkE?t=331 Updated the question above with a visual example of what I mean.

Comment: You should ask one question per thread ... you are looking probably for IK rig (Invers Kinematics) or like your link [Rigify add-on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9q5I3cyYS2Y)

Comment: For beginner is probably the fastest way to upload your character into Mixamo site let run through auto-rig  than download [Control-Rig add-on](https://substance3d.adobe.com/plugins/mixamo-in-blender/) ... or buy Auto-Rig Pro add-on